Strange behavior of the period of the reciprocal of a prime number's repeating decimal
So, I was messing around a bit in Desmos and WolframAlpha, seeing how large the repeating decimals could be when written as it's reciprocal.
I made a graph, with the the x-axis representing the nth prime number, and the y-axis representing the period of it's decimal expansion.[afformentioned graph][1]
If you look at the image, you can see two very obvious lines, with one at about half the slope.
Is there a reason for this pattern? I'm still very new to math stuff, so whatever answer exists is probably much beyond my knowledge.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/lQg3hZE9.png

Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number Also https://oeis.org/A001913
